Connection to a PowerBI datamart in Azure Data
I am simply looking to connect an existing PowerBI datamart as an Azure SQL database in SQL Server Management Studio, which I can since there is an option for authenticating with Microsoft Entra with MFA. But when I try to connect to this datamart in Azure Data Factory as an Azure SQL data source, I am very confused as to how to connect to it.
There is no SQL username/password to use with SQL Authentication method (since Azure SQL database for a datamart is automatically created) and rest of the methods are quite complex to understand and I'm not sure how they work.
Auth types
Any help appreciated.
